# Get Network Out of proteins of interest

Tags: database, protein-interaction, network, proteomics

I have generated a list of Proteins using oncogeenes and suppressor genes of cancer. 
I have 5827 mapping identifier for 3916 interactions using STRINGdb R package  . 
How do I build a network of 200k protein?

```
Identifiers.csv 

"","mapping_identifier"
"1","9606.ENSP00000003084"
"2","9606.ENSP00000003100"
"3","9606.ENSP00000004921"
"4","9606.ENSP00000004982"
"5","9606.ENSP00000005178"
```

and these are the interactions

```
"","from","to","neighborhood","neighborhood_transferred","fusion","cooccurence","homology","coexpression","coexpression_transferred","experiments","experiments_transferred","database","database_transferred","textmining","textmining_transferred","combined_score"
"1","9606.ENSP00000163416","9606.ENSP00000240851",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,481,0,481
"2","9606.ENSP00000163416","9606.ENSP00000263967",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,195,0,195
"3","9606.ENSP00000163416","9606.ENSP00000270202",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,163,0,163
```

Comment: Have you tried biostars.org? I think they are far more suited to computational questions.

Comment: Or you could try https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: What form is your data in, it would be helpful if you could post the first 10 lines of data.

Comment: @emilliman5     I edited the question  and I'll try bioinformatics.stackexchange